# Creating links inside of JSON and injecting it into the dom through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m a bit new to Angular and I am trying to modify some data that I am binding based upon the output of a regular expression. The issue is I am trying to create elements with ‘ng-click’ within this text that call a function search() and passes it the regular expressions value. For example, I would want to take data I received from an ajax call that looks like this:

```
"{\
    name: 'foo@1.0',\
    children: [\"bar@1.0\", \"baz@1.0\"],\
    ...\
}"
```

and bind it to the html in this format

```
<pre>
{
    name: '<a ng-click="search('foo@1.0')>"foo@1.0'</a>,
    children: [
        "<a ng-click="search('bar@1.0')>bar@1.0</a>", 
        "<a ng-click="search('baz@1.0')>baz@1.0</a>",
    ]
    ...
}
</pre>
```

There is one last gotcha. Due to the JSON I am receiving requiring some additional features it **can not be parsed as valid JSON**

My current method of solving this is taking a regular expression to find all names that look like `name@1.0` and surrounding them with `<a ng-click="search($event)"></a>` and do it jQuery style but Id have a hard time believing that this was the correct way of doing this.

Does anyone have a better method of solving this problem?

Comment: Well your JSON is invalid so your options are writing a PARSER for your specific flavor of JSON or regexing which is what youre doing

Comment: Perhaps the question was poorly phrased? I am wondering if anyone knows of a way that I can leverage angular's templating capabilities instead of writing javascript for formatting and modifying this string.

Comment: oh nevermind, i thought your problem was with extracting data out of a string that is not a valid JSON, let me try to answer it

Comment: what is the final html format that you want to see? the one you mentioned in your question is not really html

Comment: Right. I am just wrapping it in <pre></pre> I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to parse your string and extract your data as needed, add it to the scope and then use ng-repeat in your template

yourDirective.js

```
yourApp.directive('yourDirective', [function () {
return {
    templateUrl: 'yourDirective.html', 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // extract your data from the string and store it on thescope
    scope.name = 'foo@1.0';
    scope.children = [
      'bar@1.0',
      'baz@1.0'
    ]
    scope.search = function(val) {
      console.log('searching for', val);
    }

  };

}]);
```

yourDirective.html

```
<pre>
{
    name: '<a ng-click="search(name)">{{name}}</a>',
    children: [
    <a ng-repeat="child in children" ng-click="search(child)">{{child}}</a>
    ]
}
</pre>
```

usage:

```
<your-directive></your-directive>
```